# Shortcodes does not work in my generated widget textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

I generated custom widget textarea.

Normal text work but when I put shortcode (like:`[contact-form-7 id="538" title="widget_subscription"]`) in textarea then shortcodes do not work.

```
// Enable shortcodes in text widgets 
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

I use this code function.php file.

[image: print direct shortcode]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "shortcodes do not work" - can you give an example?

Comment: I use Contact form 7, use subscribe form  widget area . I generated custom widget textarea. Then use contact form 7 subscribe form shortcode but this shortcode print plain text not a subscribe box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this code:

```
/* WP function to add_shortcode support. */
add_shortcode('your-shortcode', 'do_shortcode');

/* Your callable */
function do_shortcode(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code to your theme’s functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```